# How do I change a property of all DatePickers in my project? (javaFX)

Tags: javafx, datepicker, javafx-datepicker

I have multiple DatePickers in my project and I want to make it so that the user cannot edit the text field and so they can't select a date before todays date on all of them.
I know how to do this to individual DatePickers but **I want a way to apply this to all of them**.
Here's the code I would use for them individually:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.getEditor().setDisable(true);
datePicker.getEditor().setOpacity(1);
datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(date, empty);
                    setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(LocalDate.now()) < 0 );
                }
            });
```

Edit:
As James_D commented I could just put these commands in a method which is the solution I used. Using a builder for this is also interesting, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: How are you creating them? If you're creating them in Java (rather than FXML), just create a method that creates a new `DatePicker`, configures it as in the code you posted, and returns it. If FXML, then create a method such as `private void configureDatePickers(DatePicker... pickers) { ... }` and pass them all to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some kind of creational pattern, e.g. a builder pattern.

Create an implementation of `Builder<DatePicker>`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.util.Builder;

public class DatePickerBuilder implements Builder<DatePicker>{

    public DatePicker build() {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.getEditor().setDisable(true);
        datePicker.getEditor().setOpacity(1);
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(LocalDate.now()) < 0 );
            }
        });
        return datePicker ; 

    }
}
```

If you're creating your `DatePicker`s in Java code, you can simply instantiate a `DatePickerBuilder` and use it:

```
private final DatePickerBuilder datePickerBuilder = new DatePickerBuilder();

// ...

// any time you need a `DatePicker` do
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build();
```

If you're using FXML, you can wrap the `DatePickerBuilder` in a custom `BuilderFactory`:

```
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.util.Builder;
import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

public class DatePickerBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {

    private final BuilderFactory defaultFactory ;
    private final DatePickerBuilder builder ;
    
    public DatePickerBuilderFactory() {
        defaultFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();
        builder = new DatePickerBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
        if (type == DatePicker.class) {
            return builder;
        } else return defaultFactory.getBuilder(type) ;
    }
    
    
}
```

which you can then supply to your `FXMLLoader`:

```
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new DatePickerBuilderFactory());
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

Deprecation note:

The individual `Builder` classes defined in JavaFX version 2.0 were deprecated in version 8.0 due to an implementation error, and removed in version 9 as there was no clean way to fix that error.

However, the `BuilderFactory` and `Builder` interfaces are still supported and used by the `FXMLLoader`, so this code is still supported.

Comment: Isn't that overly complicated? Why not simply extend `DatePicker` and use this subclass everywhere?

Comment: @julien.giband It's generally a bad (terrible) idea to use inheritance solely to configure an object. Inheritance should be used to provide additional functionality. See "Effective Java" or, bluntly, any OO text book that goes beyond the very basics. This approach is way more flexible an maintainable, especially if you're using FXML, because all the configuration is (or at least can be made) completely independent  of the layout code.

Comment: E.g. With a slight modification to the builder factory (to support a user-supplied underlying builder factory, instead of just assuming the default), you can easily decorate multiple builder factors with others, and independently customize the creation of different elements in FXML without touching the FXML file.